# Cheap Wi-Fi enabled Android or other programmable device

Tags: android, wifi, device

Does anyone know of a cheap Android or programmable device that has wifi?

I need it for a project for a company that needs a Wi-Fi handheld device for the shop floor.

I'm not too fussed about the language the device uses though I'm not really interested in the iTouch as there's no intention to release the app in the app store and I don`t really want to jail break everybody's iTouch.

Ideally it would be small, iTouch size for example and relatively cheap $100 or less. Nothing fancy, just ability to write a simple UI and have Wi-Fi. Voice is not needed.

Not too fussed about touch or qwerty keyboard either.

Comment: You can actually distribute an iPod / iPhone app to up to 100 devices without going through the app store, so depending on your scale / expected expansion that might still be an option. I think you can go further than that with one of Apple's enterprise agreements but I can't find details easily.

Comment: I think you can get an enterprise license with Apple and release adhoc app updates directly to devices through iTunes.  This requires updating a provisioning file with each device ID you want to run the application on, but you can completely skip the app store in this manner.

Comment: Thanks I didn`t know about the 100 devices limit or the enterprise license. But I`d still rather have a device that invovles no license or limit

Answer (score 0):

How cheap is cheap? On the weekend I searched eBay for "android slate" and found a bunch at US $99. I bought one immediately. It may not have the world's fastest CPU or a heap o' RAM, but at that price, how can I complain?

Like you, I want to develop apps for use in an industrial situation. I'll list voice as a feature if I use handphones, but don't really need it.

Would you please publish your final purchase decision here and I will likewise if I find a "better" option.

Bear in mind that it's not all about the cheapness of the device and consider the development effort.

Android has at least 2 good things going for it.

1) Generally programmed in Java (although you can use C & C++ if you jump through a few hoops). I may be wrong but it seems that new grads these days only know java (no offence intended to anyone reading this) and even "old hands" with C++ can quickly pick it up.

2) Android was designed from the start for developers  and has an excellent development environment and good tools.

I bought a bunch of Android books and really liked [Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988673), but you might want to check Amazon for readers 5 star votes.

And I have just noticed [Android Wireless Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321627091) which I will have to buy; I think that you might benefit from it too.

---

Oh, and if you want to outsource any development at competitive rates ... ;-)

Comment: Do you have a link to the "android slate" device you mention? I googled it and I found a HP app, a future Dell mini 5 device and several other possibilities. I would ebay it but our company overlords have decreed ebay to be blocked.
I did find a good page on Gizmodo comparing different slates http://gizmodo.com/5459308/slate-showdown-ipad-vs-hp-slate-vs-joojoo-vs-android-tablets--more-updated However a slate is probably too large for my needs it needs to be able to fit in a pocket

Comment: There was also the ziilabs egg product that looks interesting http://www.ziilabs.com/products/platforms/ziiegg.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There were some cheap Android devices at http://dealextreme.com